# JqueryUI autocomplete PHP JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json, jquery-ui

I'm actually developping an autocomplete for names in my form.

Here is my Jquery code :

```
$page->appendJs(<<<JS
$(document).ready(function()
{
          $.ajax({
               url: 'jsonClients.php',
               type: 'POST',
               dataType: 'json',
               data: 'client' : $("#client").val(),
               success: function(data){
                     $('#client').autocomplete(
                     {
                           source: data,
                           minLength: 1
                     });
               }
          });
});
```

JS
);

My input is

```
<input type='text' id='client' name='client'>
```

My jsonClients.php is working, it needs a client parameters.
I never made any jquery before, so i'm kinda lost.

EDIT :

Json

```
$json = array();

while($client = $requete->fetch()) {
    array_push($json, array('nom' => $client['CLI_NOM']));
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Parameters are sent via the `data:` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be data: {'client' : $("#client").val()} instead of "data: 'client' : $("#client").val()". 
Look at this [example](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#example-0). So code which is below should work properly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $.ajax({
           url: 'jsonClients.php',
           type: 'POST',
           dataType: 'json',
           data: {'client' : $("#client").val()},
           success: function(data){
                 $('#client').autocomplete(
                 {
                       source: data,
                       minLength: 1
                 });
           }
      });
});
```

Comment: Ok it works, but the only thing i get as autocomplete is a lot of small height, full screen width rectangles as result, without anything in :<

Comment: What do you receive from server? I mean what is in data variable?

Comment: $json = array();

while($client = $requete->fetch()) {
 array_push($json, array('nom' => $client['CLI_NOM']));
}

echo json_encode($json);

So, each client is an array with only 'nom' as attributes

Comment: It should be dimensional array. Why not to push only $client['CLI_NOM']? Like $json[] = $client['CLI_NOM'];

Comment: Because i'm a student trying to learn and I used to make one array with name for each attributes per object, so even if there is only one attributes I did it. Changed it :)

Comment: Does autocomplete work?

Comment: No, each rectangles are still small and empty

Comment: Can you show content of data variable?

Comment: Would you have a command to do it ? Can't access to firefox (& firebug) in this company ..

Comment: If content of data variable has following format: ['name1', 'name2'] autocomplete will work properly

Comment: Here is the result of the JSON for 'poi' as parameter
["POIRIER","POITOUT"]

Comment: If I type "poi" in my input text, i have 3 small & empty rectangles which appear

Comment: Debug your response from server. If response is ["POIRIER","POITOUT"]  it works, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gKVKm/1153/) is example

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you redesign your app:
First declare autocomplete, then callback action.
[Great example](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp)

```
$( "#city" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "jsonClients.php",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        client: request.term
      },
      success: function( data ) {
        //do action
      }
    });
  }
});
```